# How to implement platform independent credential store for PowerShell?

Tags: .net, powershell

Now that [PowerShell is available for Linux, Mac OS X and Windows](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), I need to replace the [PowerShell Credentials Manager](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Credentials-d44c3cde) script with a platform independent implementation. What would be the best approach, ideally using .NET Core?